# Java regex lookbehind issue with quantifiers

Tags: java, regex, lookbehind

I'm using a Java regex pattern in an application that only allows access to the whole match value (that is, I cannot use capturing groups).

I am trying to extract values from my sample text:

```
C02 SURVEY  : 2010 F10446P BONAPARTE 2D
```

In the above example I need to check for the keyword `SURVEY` and have to extract value after that `:`. And I wanted my output to be:

> 2010 F10446P BONAPARTE 2D

I used the pattern `(?<=(?i)survey\s{2}[:])(?:(?![\n]).)*`

In this pattern, I have hardcoded the spaces to be 2 (`\s{2}`) which may vary and not constant value.

I need to use quantifiers with lookbehind operation.

If any other option is there please let me know.

Comment: Remove the lookbehind and use a capturing group over the pattern you need to extract. Btw a dot does not match a newline. Use `(?i)survey\s*:(.*)`

Comment: What is the regex engine?

Comment: My application in turn uses java to extract the match.So the complete match will be returned

Comment: Lookbehinds in Java doesn't support infinite-width patterns but it supports predefined limits: `(?i)(?<=survey\s{1,999}:).*`

Comment: @DeviN Please clarify. Are you using it in Java code or some app that only returns a whole group zero match value?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I m using it in app which returns only group zero match

Comment: Good, then try `(?i)(?<=survey\s{0,100}:).*` to match zero or more chars after a `survey` and zero to 100 whitespaces followed with `:`. If it is Java regex engine, it should support limiting quantifiers in the lookbehind.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew. With predefined limits its working now.  Thanks.

Comment: @revo As you said ,Java doesn't support infinite width.But with predefined limits it worked. Thanks

Comment: @DeviN: I posted an answer with explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may leverage a feature in a Java regex engine that is called [*"constrained width lookbehind"*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookaround_support):

> Java accepts quantifiers within lookbehind, as long as the length of the matching strings falls within a pre-determined range. For instance, `(?<=cats?)` is valid because it can only match strings of three or four characters. Likewise, `(?<=A{1,10})` is valid.

That means, you may replace the `{2}` limiting quantifier with a limiting quantifier with both minimum and maximum values, e.g. `{0,100}` to allow zero to a hundred whitespace symbols. Adjust them as you see fit.

Besides, you needn't use a tempered greedy token `(?:(?![\n]).)*` as the dot in Java regex does not match a newline. Just replace it with `.*` to match any zero or more chars other than newline. So, your pattern might look as simple as `(?i)(?<=survey\s{0,100}:).*`.